# How do I switch java versions to an earlier version in Fedora 17?

Tags: java, fedora

I just installed Fedora 17. I'm setting up the Android Build Environment and need Java.

I downloaded and installed jdk-6u32-linux-amd64.rpm I ran

```
java -version
```

and it spit out the correct version.

Well a day or two later i tried my first compile in Fedora 17 and it complained about java and failed. I ran java -version again and low and behold it spits out

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_03-icedtea"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (fedora-2.1.fc17.7-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode)
```

I'm stumped. I mean, i've run the update/upgrade commands since i installed but i didn't think that updated full version revisions...
So, I ran

```
alternatives --config java
```

and that only gave me the java 1.7 version.

While digging around more I discovered that the recommended version of Java for the build environment is jdk-6u27-linux-x64-rpm.bin so I downloaded that from here: [Oracle Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u27-download-440405.html)

When I ran:

```
sudo sh jdk-6u27-linux-x64-rpm.bin
```

it returned:

```
Unpacking...
Checksumming...
Extracting...
UnZipSFX 5.50 of 17 February 2002, by Info-ZIP (Zip-Bugs@lists.wku.edu).
  inflating: jdk-6u27-linux-amd64.rpm  
  inflating: sun-javadb-common-10.6.2-1.1.i386.rpm  
  inflating: sun-javadb-core-10.6.2-1.1.i386.rpm  
  inflating: sun-javadb-client-10.6.2-1.1.i386.rpm  
  inflating: sun-javadb-demo-10.6.2-1.1.i386.rpm  
  inflating: sun-javadb-docs-10.6.2-1.1.i386.rpm  
  inflating: sun-javadb-javadoc-10.6.2-1.1.i386.rpm  
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
    package jdk-2000:1.6.0_32-fcs.x86_64 (which is newer than jdk-2000:1.6.0_27-fcs.x86_64) is already installed

Done.
```

so now I'm confused. I ran:

```
alternatives --config java
```

again but it's still only returning 1.7 so I don't know what to do.I want to end up with 6u27 as the installed and functional version of the JDK. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

After you unpack the linux bin, You have to let system know.

> alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /path/to/your/java 10

then you can config it with

> alternatives --config java

Answer (score 0):

put 6u27 in your path in stead of the 1.7 version and should be ok,or just run your applciation with the jre in your 6u27 installation in stead of using the one in your path

you can install several version, just make sure you run with the correct one